# Can we send IP request to a user by knowing their mobile number?

Tags: ip

i.e request/alert for a user in my contact list with the help of data services of  service provider and Is there any chance of getting an acknowledgement from the specified user using the data services?

Comment: Remember that not all mobile connections necessarily have an IP in the first place - mobile data might be disabled, or the phone might not even support it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Only the mobile service provider has the current mapping between a mobile number and the current IP address of a phone. This means that you cannot contact another user using an IP based data service just by knowing its mobile number.

Comment: Additionally, even if you know the IP Address, many non-business service providers would block all uninitiated incoming packets for security reasons.

Comment: @LieRyan Or so that they can use NAT to assign multiple customers the same IP, and thus reduce IP usage.

Comment: Just take a look at the "ifconfig" output of your phone on mobile data, more than likely you have been assigned an IP address in a private range.

Comment: Then,for example,Whatsapp uses only IP address for whatsapp calling and not my mobile number?

Comment: @David1029: Whatsapp using the mobile number as a real phone number only for initial setup and validation (i.e. SMS). After that it is only used as an identifier to match your contacts with registered users etc. It is not using the phone number to find your current IP, instead you contact the Whatsapp server to show that you are online and they can contact you this way.